# Excel VBA: getting row of clicked button

Tags: excel, vba, button, row, click

I am trying to make a button in Excel which copies a certain range of cells from the active workbook to another workbook. The copying of this range works perfectly when I specify a fixed range, but I am stumped on how to figure out the row of the clicked button.

Every row contains 7 or so cells, and the 8th cell contains a shape with a macro attached to it (the button).
When the user presses this button the 7 cells on the same row as the row containing the pressed button need to be copied.

Using ActiveCell is of no use, since pressing the button doesn't actually set that cell as active. I searched around a lot but I can't seem to find how to obtain this value.
Once I have the row number of the clicked button I can figure the rest out on my own.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Each `Shape` has `TopLeftCell` property. It contains a cell within which the top left corner of the shape resides.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. I was also wondering how to get the name of the shape that was clicked, but after some searching around I found this: ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name. I'll try working with the TopLeftCell property of the shape and let you know when it's working. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Got it fully working: MsgBox("Row of pressed button: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row). Thanks again!

Comment: How do I get the Colum letter? For example, column is 3 but I want 'C' returned.

Comment: @user3020047 https://stackoverflow.com/q/12796973/11683. How is it related?

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
Sub Mainscoresheet() 
     ' Mainlineup Macro
    Dim b As Object, cs As Integer 
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller) 
    With b.TopLeftCell 
        cs = .Column 
    End With 
    MsgBox "Column Number " & cs 
End Sub
```

Comment: Very helpful with dynamicly generated buttons.

Comment: Is that hyperlink still good?

Comment: Hmm, no, that linked post isn't relevant. I've removed it, thanks user

Answer (score 8):

Excellent answer. Btw It also works for Rownumber!

```
'Same for rownumbers!
Sub Mainscoresheet() 
     ' Mainlineup Macro
    Dim b As Object, RowNumber As Integer 
    Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller) 
    With b.TopLeftCell 
        RowNumber = .Row
    End With 
    MsgBox "Row Number " & RowNumber 
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This works too!  Selects the cell that the generated button resides in (knew it was in column "K" but that could be calculated too!.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("K" & ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row).Select
```