# Function to convert column number to letter?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-udf

Does anyone have an Excel VBA function which can return the column letter(s) from a number?

For example, entering *100* should return `CV`.

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106465/excel-column-number-from-column-name

Comment: @FrancisDean that is the reverse of this question which is looking for the address from the number

Comment: @brettdj The answer linked shows both number to letter and letter to number.

Comment: @FrancisDean fair point, I looked at the question title in the link to rather than the accepted answer

Answer (score 254, accepted):

This function returns the column letter for a given column number.

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

*testing code for column 100*

```
Sub Test()
    MsgBox Col_Letter(100)
End Sub
```

Comment: You can add the `(0)` to the end of the Split command if you want to save yourself a variable declaration and extra line of code. eg `Col_letter = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)`

Comment: That is quite correct, but I thought it more readable to use several lines.

Comment: Why bother with the Boolean params in this situation. You can do this:................................................... `v = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address, "$")(1)`

Comment: While this is very old, I have a minor addition - checking first if the number is positive, since otherwise you run into errors. if lngcol <=0 then

Comment: When using VBS, remember that `.Cells` is a property of Excel, meaning you need to use `<excel_object>.Cells()`. Otherwise, you will get a type mismatch error.

Answer (score 106):

If you'd rather not use a range object:

```
Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim c As Byte
    Dim s As String

    n = ColumnNumber
    Do
        c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
        s = Chr(c + 65) & s
        n = (n - c) \ 26
    Loop While n > 0
    ColumnLetter = s
End Function
```

Comment: Not clear why you posted a longer method with a loop on the basis of *If you'd rather not use a range object:*

Comment: @brettdj I can imagine several reasons: 1) this method is around 6x faster by my testing 2) it doesn't require access to the Excel API 3) it presumably has a smaller memory footprint.  EDIT: Also, I'm not sure why I commented on an answer over a year old :S

Comment: There's a drawback to the increased speed, though. Using the range object throws an error if you pass in an invalid column number. It works even if someone is still using Excel 2003. If you need that kind of exception, go with the range method. Otherwise, kudos to robartsd.

Comment: You could always test the input column number: `IF ColumnNumber <= 16384 Then`

Comment: `IF ColumnNumber <= Columns.Count` would be better to avoid assumptions around versions.

Comment: **For VBS users:** If you get an error `Expected ')'`, you will need to remove the `As <Type>` statements. (As Long, As Byte, As String, etc)

Comment: Another reason to use this code is if you're not in VBA but in VB, .net, etc.

Answer (score 57):

Something that works for me is:

```
Cells(Row,Column).Address
```

This will return the $AE$1 format reference for you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is exactly the answer that solved my problem. I am using another language, but it put me in the right ball park. I looked at it as pseudo code and figured it out. 

Here is what I used:
$ws.Columns[$lastCol].Rows[$lastRow].Address().Replace('$','')

Answer (score 49):

[image: I'm surprised nobody suggested: Columns(Column Index).Address]

- **For example:** `MsgBox Columns( 9347 ).Address` *returns* <sub>[image: $MUM:$MUM]</sub>.

---

**To return *ONLY* the column letter**(s): **`Split((Columns(`***`Column Index`***`).Address(,0)),":")(0)`**

- **For example:** `MsgBox Split((Columns( 2734 ).Address(,0)),":")(0)` *returns* <sub>[image: DAD]</sub>.

---

[image: More Examples]

---

Comment: This one works for me in Office 365: string col = Worksheet.Columns[column].Address; return col.Substring(col.IndexOf(":") + 2); For some reason other expressions, such as Range = Worksheet.Cells[1,column], were throwing errors (either in the Cells call or when I tried to take the address, can't remember - sorry - which lines where throwing in which specific cases.)

Comment: Even shorter to return *only* the column letter(s): `Split(Columns(idx).Address, "$")(2)` - instead of *`Split((Columns(idx).Address(,0)),":")(0)`*, where `idx` is a Long representing the Column Index.

Answer (score 20):

Just one more way to do this. [Brettdj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797190/3357935) made me think of this, but if you use this method you don't have to use a variant array, you can go directly to a string.

```
ColLtr = Cells(1, ColNum).Address(True, False)
ColLtr = Replace(ColLtr, "$1", "")
```

or can make it a little more compact with this

```
ColLtr = Replace(Cells(1, ColNum).Address(True, False), "$1", "")
```

Notice this does depend on you referencing row 1 in the cells object.

Answer (score 19):

And a solution using recursion:

```
Function ColumnNumberToLetter(iCol As Long) As String

    Dim lAlpha As Long
    Dim lRemainder As Long

    If iCol <= 26 Then
        ColumnNumberToLetter = Chr(iCol + 64)
    Else
        lRemainder = iCol Mod 26
        lAlpha = Int(iCol / 26)
        If lRemainder = 0 Then
            lRemainder = 26
            lAlpha = lAlpha - 1
        End If
        ColumnNumberToLetter = ColumnNumberToLetter(lAlpha) & Chr(lRemainder + 64)
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Cut-and-paste perfect to convert numbers greater than 676. Thanks!

Comment: The remainder can never be more than 26 so why not an integer rather than long?

Comment: @Caltor Unless you have a special purpose for using an Integer, like calling an API that demands one for example, you should never choose an Integer over a Long. VBA is optimized for Longs. VBA processes Longs faster than Integers.

Comment: @ExcelHero I didn't know that. Doesn't a Long take more memory than an Integer though?

Comment: @Caltor Indeed a Long is 32 bits, while an Integer is 16. But that does not matter in modern computing. 25 years ago... it mattered a lot. But today (even 15 years ago) the difference is totally inconsequential.

Answer (score 12):

This is available through using a formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),4),"1","")
```

and so also can be written as a VBA function as requested:

```
Function ColName(colNum As Integer) As String
    ColName = Split(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, colNum).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 11):

This is a version of [robartsd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366979/3357935) (with the flavor of [Jan Wijninckx's one line solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21820200/3357935)), using recursion instead of a loop.

```
Public Function ColumnLetter(Column As Integer) As String
    If Column < 1 Then Exit Function
    ColumnLetter = ColumnLetter(Int((Column - 1) / 26)) & Chr(((Column - 1) Mod 26) + Asc("A"))
End Function
```

I've tested this with the following inputs:

```
1   => "A"
26  => "Z"
27  => "AA"
51  => "AY"
702 => "ZZ"
703 => "AAA" 
-1  => ""
-234=> ""
```

Comment: I've just noticed that this is essentially the same as Nikolay Ivanov's solution, which makes mine a little less novel. I'll leave it up because it shows a slightly different approach for a few of the minutia

Comment: Good solution for two reasons: not using any object (such as range, cell, and so on); very compact definition.

Answer (score 10):

[robertsd's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366979/3357935) is elegant, yet to make it future-proof, change the declaration of n to type long

In case you want a formula to avoid macro's, here is something that works up to column 702 inclusive

```
=IF(A1>26,CHAR(INT((A1-1)/26)+64),"")&CHAR(MOD(A1-1,26)+65)
```

where A1 is the cell containing the column number to be converted to letters.

Comment: As addition, here is the [formula that converts a column letter to a column number](https://superuser.com/a/1712165/661280) in similar style.

Answer (score 7):

**LATEST UPDATE**: Please ignore the function below, @SurasinTancharoen managed to alert me that it is broken at `n = 53`.
For those who are interested, here are other broken values just below `n = 200`:

[image: Certain values of]

[Please use @brettdj function for all your needs. It even works for Microsoft Excel latest maximum number of columns limit: `16384` should gives `XFD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797190/3858066)

[image]

**END OF UPDATE**

---

The function below is provided by Microsoft:

```
Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

Source: [How to convert Excel column numbers into alphabetical characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833402)

APPLIES TO

- Microsoft Office **Excel 2007**
- Microsoft Excel 2002 Standard Edition
- Microsoft Excel 2000 Standard Edition
- Microsoft Excel 97 Standard Edition

Comment: For reference, this pukes with larger column sets as Chr() doesn't handle large numbers well.

Comment: This has a bug. Try ConvertToLetter(53) which should have been 'BA' but it will be fail.

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen Thank you very much for noting this flaw. 
I have never thought Microsoft would provide a broken function 
as they are the one who created Microsoft Excel themselves. 
I will abandon this function from now on and will use @brettdj function 
that even correct up to latest Microsoft Excel maximum number of column limit `Col_Letter(16384) = "XFD"`

Comment: And where on Earth does this "divide by 27" comes from? Last I checked there are 26 letters. This is why this code breaks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a function based on [@DamienFennelly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20131777/3357935) above. If you give me a thumbs up, give him a thumbs up too! :P

```
Function outColLetterFromNumber(iCol as Integer) as String
    sAddr = Cells(1, iCol).Address
    aSplit = Split(sAddr, "$")
    outColLetterFromNumber = aSplit(1)
End Function
```

Comment: Good one, but how is it different from the accepted answer?

Comment: @loannis I based mine on DamianFennelly's answer, not the accepted one. But yeah, mine looks a lot like the accepted answer, except one line is broken into two to make it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple way using Excel power: Use `Range.Cells.Address` property, this way:

```
strCol = Cells(1, lngRow).Address(xlRowRelative, xlColRelative)
```

This will return the address of the desired column on row 1. Take it of the `1`:

```
strCol = Left(strCol, len(strCol) - 1)
```

Note that it so fast and powerful that you can return column addresses that even exists!

Substitute `lngRow` for the desired column number using `Selection.Column` property!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple one liner that can be used.

```
ColumnLetter = Mid(Cells(Row, LastColA).Address, 2, 1)
```

It will only work for a 1 letter column designation, but it is nice for simple cases.  If you need it to work for exclusively 2 letter designations, then you could use the following:

```
ColumnLetter = Mid(Cells(Row, LastColA).Address, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work regardless of what column inside your one code line for cell thats located in row X, in column Y:

```
Mid(Cells(X,Y).Address, 2, instr(2,Cells(X,Y).Address,"$")-2)
```

If you have a cell with unique defined name "Cellname":

```
Mid(Cells(1,val(range("Cellname").Column)).Address, 2, instr(2,Cells(1,val(range("Cellname").Column)).Address,"$")-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

So I'm late to the party here, but I want to contribute another answer that no one else has addressed yet that doesn't involve arrays. You can do it with simple string manipulation.

```
Function ColLetter(Col_Index As Long) As String

    Dim ColumnLetter As String

    'Prevent errors; if you get back a number when expecting a letter, 
    '    you know you did something wrong.
    If Col_Index <= 0 Or Col_Index >= 16384 Then
        ColLetter = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    ColumnLetter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, Col_Index).Address     'Address in $A$1 format
    ColumnLetter = Mid(ColumnLetter, 2, InStr(2, ColumnLetter, "$") - 2)  'Extracts just the letter

    ColLetter = ColumnLetter
End Sub
```

After you have the input in the format `$A$1`, use the `Mid` function, start at position 2 to account for the first `$`, then you find where the second `$` appears in the string using `InStr`, and then subtract 2 off to account for that starting position.

This gives you the benefit of being adaptable for the whole range of possible columns. Therefore, `ColLetter(1)` gives back "A", and  `ColLetter(16384)` gives back "XFD", which is the last possible column for my Excel version.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to get the column name

```
Sub column()

cell=cells(1,1)
column = Replace(cell.Address(False, False), cell.Row, "")
msgbox column

End Sub
```

I hope it helps =)

Answer (score 1):

The solution from brettdj works fantastically, but if you are coming across this as a potential solution for the same reason I was, I thought that I would offer my alternative solution.

The problem I was having was scrolling to a specific column based on the output of a MATCH() function. Instead of converting the column number to its column letter parallel, I chose to temporarily toggle the reference style from A1 to R1C1. This way I could just scroll to the column number without having to muck with a VBA function. To easily toggle between the two reference styles, you can use this VBA code:

```
Sub toggle_reference_style()

If Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1 Then
  Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
Else
  Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Furthering on brettdj answer, here is to make the input of column number optional. If the column number input is omitted, the function returns the column letter of the cell that calls to the function. I know this can also be achieved using merely `ColumnLetter(COLUMN())`, but i thought it'd be nice if it can cleverly understand so.

```
Public Function ColumnLetter(Optional ColumnNumber As Long = 0) As String
    If ColumnNumber = 0 Then
        ColumnLetter = Split(Application.Caller.Address(True, False, xlA1), "$")(0)
    Else
        ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address(True, False, xlA1), "$")(0)
    End If
End Function
```

The trade off of this function is that it would be very very slightly slower than brettdj's answer because of the `IF` test. But this could be felt if the function is repeatedly used for very large amount of times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a late answer, just for simplistic approach using `Int()` and `If` in case of 1-3 character columns:

```
Function outColLetterFromNumber(i As Integer) As String

    If i < 27 Then       'one-letter
        col = Chr(64 + i)
    ElseIf i < 677 Then  'two-letter
        col = Chr(64 + Int(i / 26)) & Chr(64 + i - (Int(i / 26) * 26))
    Else                 'three-letter
        col = Chr(64 + Int(i / 676)) & Chr(64 + Int(i - Int(i / 676) * 676) / 26)) & Chr(64 + i - (Int(i - Int(i / 676) * 676) / 26) * 26))
    End If

    outColLetterFromNumber = col

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function fColLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
  On Error GoTo errLabel
  fColLetter = Split(Columns(lngCol).Address(, False), ":")(1)
  Exit Function
errLabel:
  fColLetter = "%ERR%"
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, a simple function in Pascal (Delphi).

```
function GetColLetterFromNum(Sheet : Variant; Col : Integer) : String;
begin
  Result := Sheet.Columns[Col].Address;  // from Col=100 --> '$CV:$CV'
  Result := Copy(Result, 2, Pos(':', Result) - 2);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

This formula will give the column based on a range (i.e., *A1*), where range is a single cell.  If a multi-cell range is given it will return the top-left cell.  Note, both cell references must be the same:

MID(CELL("address",*A1*),2,SEARCH("$",CELL("address",*A1*),2)-2)

How it works:

CELL("property","range") returns a specific value of the range depending on the property used.  In this case the cell address.
The address property returns a value $[col]$[row], i.e. A1 -> $A$1.
The MID function parses out the column value between the $ symbols.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GiveAddress()
    Dim Chara As String
    Chara = ""
    Dim Num As Integer
    Dim ColNum As Long
    ColNum = InputBox("Input the column number")

    Do
        If ColNum < 27 Then
            Chara = Chr(ColNum + 64) & Chara
            Exit Do
        Else
            Num = ColNum / 26
            If (Num * 26) > ColNum Then Num = Num - 1
            If (Num * 26) = ColNum Then Num = ((ColNum - 1) / 26) - 1
            Chara = Chr((ColNum - (26 * Num)) + 64) & Chara
            ColNum = Num
        End If
    Loop

    MsgBox "Address is '" & Chara & "'."
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Column letter from column number can be extracted using formula by following steps 
1. Calculate the column address using ADDRESS formula 
2. Extract the column letter using MID and FIND function 

Example:
1. ADDRESS(1000,1000,1) 
  results  $ALL$1000
2. =MID(F15,2,FIND("$",F15,2)-2)
  results ALL asuming F15 contains result of step 1

In one go we can write
 MID(ADDRESS(1000,1000,1),2,FIND("$",ADDRESS(1000,1000,1),2)-2)

Answer (score -1):

this is only for REFEDIT  ... generaly use uphere code
shortly version... easy to be read and understood / 
it use poz of  $

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()

    Me.Label1.Caption = NOtoLETTER(RefEdit1.Value) ' you may assign to a variable  var=....'

End Sub

Function NOtoLETTER(REFedit)

    Dim First As Long, Second As Long

    First = InStr(REFedit, "$")                 'first poz of $
    Second = InStr(First + 1, REFedit, "$")     'second poz of $

    NOtoLETTER = Mid(REFedit, First + 1, Second - First - 1)   'extract COLUMN LETTER

End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

Cap A is 65 so:

`MsgBox Chr(ActiveCell.Column + 64)`

Found in: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?6103-Solved-get-column-letter

Answer (score -2):

what about just converting to the ascii number and using Chr() to convert back to a letter?

col_letter = Chr(Selection.Column + 96)