# Convert column numeric value to alpha

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VBA function to convert column number to letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/vba-function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)

I need to display a msgbox that shows the last used column.

Right now the columns numeric value is displayed but can it be converted into its alpha character equivalent?

Ex. column 5 = column E.

Thanks

Comment: Sean, thanks for the functions. They did exactly what I needed them to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get 2 methods. One relies on the excel `Cells`, so it fails if you use an invalid column:

```
Function NumToLetter(q As Long) As String

Dim Add As String
'Ignore error so it fails on an invalid cell
On Error Resume Next
Add = Cells(1, q).Address
If Len(Add) Then
    NumToLetter = Mid(Add, 2, InStr(2, Add, "$") - 2)
Else
    NumToLetter = "Invalid Cell"
End If

End Function
```

the other uses base 26, and is only limited bu the maximum value for `long`:

```
Function Num2Letter(q As Long) As String

Dim r As Long
While q > 0
    r = q Mod 26
    If r = 0 Then r = 26 ' needed for column Z
    Num2Letter = Chr(64 + r) & Num2Letter
    q = Int(q / 26) + (r = 26) ' fix for column Z
Wend

End Function
```

to test these values with a messagebox:

```
msgbox "Column 2445 is " & NumToLetter(2445) & " or " Num2Letter(2445)
```

> Column 2445 is CPA or CPA

```
msgbox "Column 42445 is " & NumToLetter(42445) & " or " Num2Letter(42445)
```

> Column 42445 is Invalid Cell or BJTM

```
msgbox "Column -1 is " & NumToLetter(-1) & " or " Num2Letter(-1)
```

> Column -1 is Invalid Cell or

Comment: Thanks for the functions. They did exactly what I needed them to do.

Answer (score 0):

This works for columns A through ZZ (as pointed out in the comments by Sean Cheshire):

```
Function ColLetter(ColNumber As Integer) As String
    ColLetter = Left(Cells(1, ColNumber).Address(False, False), 1 - (ColNumber > 26))
End Function
```

To use: `MsgBox ColLetter(oRangeObject.Column)`

Comment: this works until column 703, with is `AAA`, but this truncates it to `AA`

Comment: Ahh, right.  I never needed it past there - +1 to your more-complete answer.