# How can i get the Column letters of a cell (need to make it work past the Z column such as AA,AB)

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VBA function to convert column number to letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/vba-function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)

I want to have the column letters past the Z column,
there are many techniques for getting it before Z column but after Z, nothing seems to work
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another method:

```
Public Function ColumnLettersFromRange(rInput As Range) As String

    ColumnLettersFromRange = Split(rInput.Address, "$")(1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

This should do the job:

```
Function ColumnName(rng As Range) As String
    Dim s As String
    s = rng.Address(False, False)
    ColumnName = Left(s, Len(s) - Len(Format(rng.Row, "0")))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Using worksheet functions to calculate the column letter isn't really a good plan. Using Peter Albert's VBA method is a much nicer way to do it!

I had a go at making one using worksheet functions, just for fun :/

A-ZZ

```
=IF(A1<27,CHAR(64+A1),IF(A1<703,CHAR(64+INT(A1/26))&CHAR(A1-INT(A1/26)+64),"TOO BIG!"))
```

A-XFD (doesn't work)

```
=IF(A1<27,CHAR(64+A1),IF(A1<703,CHAR(64+INT(A1/26))&CHAR(A1-(INT(A1/26)*26)+64),CHAR(64+INT(A1/676))&CHAR(64+(INT(A1-(INT(A1/676)*676))/26))&CHAR(64+INT(A1-((INT(A1-(INT(A1/676)*676))/26)*26)))))
```

The final one falls over trying to work out the 3rd character in the address, I just cant be bothered as using it is not a good plan!

Comment: Thats the formula I ended up with (works till XFD): `=IF(QUOTIENT(COLUMN(A1),26^2),CHAR(64+QUOTIENT(COLUMN(A1),26^2)),"")&
IF(QUOTIENT(COLUMN(A1),26^1),CHAR(64+QUOTIENT(COLUMN(A1)-QUOTIENT(COLUMN(A1),26^2)*26^2,26^1)),"")&
CHAR(64+MOD(COLUMN(A1),26))
`

Comment: Try `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,A1,4),1,"")`