# Use an integer as a column reference

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hello all  I´m currently trying to use "cl.column" to establish a column to use in a loop.  The relevant part of my code is below.

The issue I´m having is that because cl.column stores the column as a number I don´t know how to reference it in my loop since it isn´t a letter.

```
for each cl in activesheet.range("A1:BZ1")
if instr(cl, "Deuda") > 0 then
StoredColumn = cl.column
end if
next cl

for each cl In Workbooks(MesActual).Worksheets("Deuda").Range(ColumnA & "8", ColumnA & CounterA)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/vba-function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, sorry for asking a redundant question I hadn´t considered the use of a function so I couldn´t find that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bit confused with your question. You are storing "c.column" in "StoredColumn" but couldn't find where you are trying to use it.

However, Whenever i required to use Range object and if i have column number instead of column letter i will try to use as below. May be this can help you.

```
Sub test()
   For Each cel In Range("A1:Z1")
     colno = cel.Column
     ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, cel.Column).Address) = cel.Column
   Next
End Sub
```

Thanks, 
Ramana