# How do I call a function inside another function in VBA?

Tags: vba, function, excel

I have a function 1 that looks like this:

```
Function myFirstFunction(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

I need to call this function in a separate function like this:

```
Function myOtherFunction(myVar as Variant) As Variant
Dim Some_Column As Range
Some_Column = Range("B4").Address

If Range((myFirstFunction(Some_Column.Column) & 65536)).End(xlUp) <> Range(myFirstFunction(Some_Column.Column) & 1) Then
...some code
End If
```

It's giving me an error, I would assume because I'm not able to use the first function in the second function. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is not passing anything back.

You probably want to change Col_Letter to myFirstFunction in the first function.

Also in the second function change 65536 to rows.count.

It will then error here:

```
Some_Column = Range("B4").Address
```

Change it to this:

```
Set Some_Column = Range("B4")
```

This is because it is defined as a range so you can't pass the address in (which is a string), you pass the object in (which you have to use Set for)

Should be all good after that.

```
Function myFirstFunction(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
myFirstFunction = vArr(0)
End Function

Function myOtherFunction(myVar As Variant) As Variant
Dim Some_Column As Range
Set Some_Column = Range("B4")

If Range((myFirstFunction(Some_Column.Column) & rows.count)).End(xlUp) <> Range(myFirstFunction(Some_Column.Column) & 1) Then
'...some code
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The problematic part is `Some_Column = Range("B4").Address`

1. `Dim Some_Column As Range` declares the variable as a reference type, which means you need to set it's reference to an object by stating `Set Some_Column = ...` and preferably release it in the end with `Set Some_Column = Nothing`.
2. `.Address` returns a `String` and not an object, so your code should be `Set Some_Column = Range("B4")` to set Some_Column as a Range.

There's an additional mistake in the first function where `Col_Letter = vArr(0)` should probably be `myFirstFunction = vArr(0)`, or the other way around. This line sets the function's returned value, `function_name = ...`.

You copied the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/vba-function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter) but if you change the function name you have to change it the whole way through.