# Excel VBA insert formula

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to insert a formula in a cell using vba using a dynamic column reference like this:

```
Fred = ConvertToLetter(ActiveCell.Column)
Bob = "=DATE(LEFT(" + Fred + "2,4),MID(" + Fred + "2,5,2),MID(" + Fred + "2,7,2))"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Bob    

Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
    Dim iAlpha As Integer
    Dim iRemainder As Integer
    iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
    iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
    If iAlpha > 0 Then
        ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
    End If
    If iRemainder > 0 Then
        ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
    End If
End Function
```

but when it runs the formula ends up with single quotes around the cell and the formula does not work like this:

```
=DATE(LEFT('AY2',4),MID('AY2',5,2),MID('AY2',7,2))
```

how do i stop the single quotes being added to allow the formula to work correctly?

Thanks

Comment: there is also a more elegant function to find the column letter [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/vba-function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)

Comment: Don't know if it *really* matters, but you really ought to use the ampersand not plus sign for string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `FormulaR1C1` property causing the problem.

Do this instead:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = Bob
```

By the way, instead of the ConvertToLetter() function, you can use this:

```
Fred = Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1)
```

Comment: Excellent works a treat, trying to be clever and reusing a recorded macro that where the R1C1 came from....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this '' (two single apostrophes) instead.

Answer (score 0):

To use R1C1 formula you'd use:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATE(LEFT(R2C,4),MID(R2C,5,2),MID(R2C,7,2))"`

R2 in the formula means Row 2.
C in the formula means the column the formula is in.

Looking at R1C1 notation:
R[-1] means this row minus 1.
C[1] means this column plus 1.
R1 means row 1
C1 means column 1
R means this row.
C means this column.

So, in cell B2 - R1C1 means cell A1.
R1C[-1] means cell A1
RC1 means cell A2.
RC means cell B2.

Hope that's clear. :)

or you can just use ActiveCell.Formula = Bob as Excel Hero said.