# How can I convert numbers to letters in VBS?

Tags: vbscript, type-conversion

I want to take a number and convert it into lowercase `a-z` letters using VBScript.

For example:

- `1` converts to `a`
- `2` converts to `b`
- `27` converts to `aa`
- `28` converts to `ab`
- and so on...

In particular I am having trouble converting numbers after 26 when converting to 2 letter cell names. (*aa*, *ab*, *ac*, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to convert column number to letter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the [`Chr(n)`](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_chr.asp) function.

This would fit your needs from `a` to `z`:

```
wscript.echo Chr(number+96)
```

<del>To represent multiple letters for numbers, (like excel would do it) you'll have to check your number for ranges and use the [`Mod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/se0w9esz.aspx) operator for modulo.</del>

---

EDIT:

There is a fast food Copy&Paste example on the web: [How to convert Excel column numbers into alphabetical characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/833402)

#### Quoted example from microsoft:

> For example: The column number is 30.
>
> The column number is divided by 27: `30 / 27 = 1.1111`, rounded down by the Int function to "1".
>
> ```
> i = 1
> ```
>
> Next Column number - (i * 26) = `30 -(1 * 26) = 30 - 26 = 4`.
>
> ```
> j = 4
> ```
>
> Convert the values to alphabetical characters separately,
>
> ```
> i = 1 = "A"
> j = 4 = "D"
> ```
>
> Combined together, they form the column designator **"AD"**.

And its code:

```
Function ConvertToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
   Dim iAlpha As Integer
   Dim iRemainder As Integer
   iAlpha = Int(iCol / 27)
   iRemainder = iCol - (iAlpha * 26)
   If iAlpha > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = Chr(iAlpha + 64)
   End If
   If iRemainder > 0 Then
      ConvertToLetter = ConvertToLetter & Chr(iRemainder + 64)
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the solutions above work for the full Excel range from A to XFD. The first example only works up to ZZ. The second example has boundry problems explained in the code comments below.

//
Function ColumnNumberToLetter(ColumnNumber As Integer) As String

```
' convert a column number to the Excel letter representation

Dim Div As Double
Dim iMostSignificant As Integer
Dim iLeastSignificant As Integer
Dim Base As Integer
Base = 26
' Column letters are base 26 starting at A=1 and ending at Z=26
' For base 26 math to work we need to adjust the input value to
' base 26 starting at 0
Div = (ColumnNumber - 1) / Base
iMostSignificant = Int(Div)
' The addition of 1 is needed to restore the  0 to 25 result value to 
' align with A to Z
iLeastSignificant = 1 + (Div - iMostSignificant) * Base
' convert number to letter
ColumnNumberToLetter = Chr(64 + iLeastSignificant)
' if the input number is larger than the base then the conversion we
' just did is the least significant letter
' Call the function again with the remaining most significant letters
If ColumnNumber > Base Then
    ColumnNumberToLetter = ColumnNumberToLetter(iMostSignificant) & ColumnNumberToLetter
End If
```

End Function
//

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function converts(n)
  Dim i, c, m
  i = n
  c = ""
  While i > 26
    m = (i mod 26)
    c = Chr(m+96) & c
    i = (i - m) / 26
  Wend
  c = Chr(i+96) & c
  converts = c
end function

WScript.Echo converts(1000)
```