# VBA How to convert a column to a number

Tags: excel, vba

In several VBA codes, I often find a column number like 180 or any other integer number.
Is there a VBA formula or a coded method to calculate that it is column "FX" without counting it manually ?

Comment: Try the link here on SO (works very nice) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter

Comment: [This solution solved my problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)