# Using variable as a column for autofilter (vba)

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'd like to use a variable as a column for autofilter in vba, I think I'm not getting the sintax right, cause it`s not working:

```
With ActiveSheet
.AutoFilterMode = False
With .Range("A1:" & LastCol + 1 & "1")
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="Approved"
.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="Open"
.AutoFilter field:=LastCol + 1, Criteria1:="1"
End With
End With
```

Comment: Is LastCol defined?

Comment: Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

Comment: It needs the letter for that syntax instead of integer. "A1:" & LastCol + 1 & "1"

Comment: Can you edit your post with the rest of the code?

Comment: actually, is that a way of getting the letter for the last column? all I have is the number (because the last column can change depending on the sheet. or.. is it a way of substituting the sintax for Range in the AutoFilter sub for a numbered column?

Comment: This answer shows how to get the letter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter

Comment: Wouldn't `LastCol + 1` be 1 column to the right of your last column?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no blank columns, you can use the [`CurrentRegion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) instead (similar to a Ctrl + A in `A1`)

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
With Cells.CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter 5, "Approved"
    .AutoFilter 6, "Open"
    .AutoFilter .Columns.Count, "1"
End With
```