# Refer column as a number in activecell.formula function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying a calculate sum product using VBA. The code is as

```
Sub Result()
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(B4:QF4,B5004:QF5004)"
End Sub
```

There is a variable in the program and the number of columns changes every time. 
I tried defining the column "QF" as a number, but this is showing an error. 
How do I define a column as a number in my code? 
I have tried the following code.

```
Sub Result()
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(B4:(" & (FinalR - j) & ")4,B(" & (FR - nobis + j + 1) & "):(" & (FinalR - j) & ")5004)"
End Sub
```

Comment: `OFFSET` and `RESIZE`  in your code you need `..B4:B" & (FinalR - j)....`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to convert column number to letter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)

Comment: I would use `.resize` like @Nathan_Sav stated `"& Range("B4").Resize(1, (FinalR - j)).Address(0,0)`  You may need to readjust your math the second is the number of columns to include.

Comment: [Avoid .Select and .Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513) - working against the `ActiveCell` is a sign that you're *Doing It Wrong™*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Sub Result()
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(B4:" & Left(Cells(1, FinalR - j).EntireColumn.Address(False, False), InStr(Cells(1, FinalR - j).EntireColumn.Address(False, False), ":") - 1) & "4,B5004:" & Left(Cells(1, FinalR - j).EntireColumn.Address(False, False), InStr(Cells(1, FinalR - j).EntireColumn.Address(False, False), ":") - 1) & "5004)"
End Sub
```

I'm assuming that `FinalR - j` gives you the column number?

Comment: `.columns(FinalR - j).address(0,0)` would suffice for the complete columns address

Comment: @Jeremy I need one more favor, How can I lock the cells. That is I want the code like below                                                                             ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(B4:QF4,$B$5004:$QF$5004)"

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.. do you mean `"=SUMPRODUCT($B$4:$QF$4,$B$5004:$QF$5004)"`?

Comment: Sir, I need the code for the formula
 "=SUMPRODUCT(B4:QF4,$B$5004:$QF$5004)"

Comment: @Raj that is what you'll see in the excel cell but for your VBA code, you'll need to enter the code I gave you because you're dynamically referencing the column