# how to make my macro work beyond column z - lastcolumn macro

Tags: excel, vba, function

```
Function lastrow(colName As String)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, colName).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
Function LastCol(rowName As Double)
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastCol = sht.Cells(rowName, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End Function
Function lastcell()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long
Dim lastletter As String
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lastrow = sht.UsedRange.Rows(sht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
lastcolumn = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
lastletter = Chr(64 + lastcolumn)
lastcell = lastletter & lastrow
End Function
```

how can i get the lastletter line to work for columns AA, AAA, AAAA etc as my routine uses the chr hack but only works on sheets A-Z.

Comment: Why do you define 3 functions, and make the last function not take the result of the first two functions? To convert a column number into a letter see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter

Comment: @Luuklag - because the first two functions return a value based on a column or a row as an argument. the third function uses .usedrange which looks at the entire sheet to find max row and columns. note that the third function does not use an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Address function of Cells():

```
lastcell = sht.Cells(lastrow,lastcolumn).Address(0,0)
```

Comment: thanks scott, that fixed the issue. elegant solution.

Comment: @DanM after the question is 15 minutes old please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: how would i change the function LastCol to return a column letter instead of a column number?

Comment: @DanM why?  in vba it is better to use Cells() with numbers than to convert to a letter that vba will then need to convert to a number.  But you can parse the return of the Address to return the letter portion, but this is the slowest method to refer to a cell.

Comment: now that i think about  it, you are right. it should return a number and not a letter. how can i parse it though, not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I use functions to find to convert the numeric column to its alpha equivalent

```
Dim mycol as string

mycol = WColNm(Mycell.Column) ‘ mycell.column is numeric. Function returns 
integer

Public Function WColNm(ColNum) as string
    WColNm = Split(Cells(1, ColNum).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Or column letters to numbers

```
Dim IntCol as integer

Intcol = WcolNum(“A”)

Public Function wcolNum(ColNm) as int
    wcolNum = Range(ColNm & 1).Column
End Function
```