# Is there a way to select an entire column using the column number in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, select, letter

I want to select an entire column in Excel using VBA code, normally I'd do that like this `Range("D:D").select`

However in the current situation I only have the column numbers and I'd like to avoid having to convert the numbers into the corresponding letter. I have found a way to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Using `.EntireColumn` :

**Code**

```
Dim ColNumner As Long
ColNumner = 5

Cells(1, ColNumner).EntireColumn.Select
```

2. Using directly `Columns(ColNumner)` :

**Code**

```
Dim ColNumner As Long
ColNumner = 5

Columns(ColNumner).Select
```

**Note**: you should stay with from using `Select`. For instance,  if you want to copy this column, you could use `Columns(ColNumner).Copy`, etc...

Answer (score 2):

```
Columns(ColNumber).EntireColumn.Select
```

e.g.

```
Columns(1).EntireColumn.Select
```

Comment: not sure why you would use `Columns(ColNumber).EntireColumn.Select` and not `Columns(ColNumber).Select` ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wish I could select both of answers as correct, but Shai's is more complete so I went with his.