# Excel Sum product values and stock then multiplie when multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have this information:

```
+---------------+---------+-------+------------+
|   Chocolate   |  Brand  | Stock | Sale value |
+---------------+---------+-------+------------+
| Chokito       | Nestlé  |  1520 | $3,50      |
| Snickers      | Mars    |  3300 | $5,20      |
| Snickers 2    | Mars    |   500 | $2,50      |
| Kit Kat       | Nestlé  |  2000 | $9,10      |
| Double Decker | Cadbury |  1000 | $2,50      |
| Idaho         | Mars    |     0 | $6,10      |
| Caramello     | Cadbury |   350 | $7,50      |
| Cadbury Daily | Cadbury |  1000 | $3,10      |
| Almond Joy    | Hershey |   500 | $1,50      |
| Twix          | Nestlé  |   999 | $4,50      |
| Zero Bar      | Hershey |   488 | $5,50      |
+---------------+---------+-------+------------+
```

Wha I want to get the total stock value for each brand. I get these values by inserting a column of of stock * value then doing a Pivot Table

```
Cadbury  $8.225,00 
Hershey  $3.434,00 
Mars     $18.410,00 
Nestlé   $28.015,50
```

But what I want to do is a formula in Excel that will get this same values.
I first tried using SUMIF but obvioulsy it didnt worked xD

I cant think of any other formula
Thanks for your help

Comment: This is a homework assignment isn't it?  Did you at least *try* to solve it yourself?

Comment: I solved it xdd

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C$2:C$12), (D$2:D$12), --(B$2:B$12=G4))
```

For a dynamic length of data,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))), (D$2:INDEX(D:D, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))), --(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))=G4))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Jeeped - you surprise me sometimes! Bored?

Comment: I guess I shouldn't talk... I just spent a *wee bit* too much time on one of the examples for [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49577009), that probably nobody would even notice if I didn't point it out...

Comment: Thanks. After posting I found this same solution, but I am getting a problem: I want to refer to the whole column like C:C; D:D and B:B cause I may get more values, but because of text headers I got an error. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @JuniorSantos must not be the *same* solution then.  :)

Comment: @JuniorSantos  you dont want to do full column references with sumproduct or any array calculations as you will wind up doing excessive calculations.  When going full column reference, better off using SUMIF or SUMIFS.

Comment: @ jeeped Does setting the end of the index within the SUMPRODUCT save on the excess calculations of using full referenced columns?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using sumif

Place the following in E2 and copy down

```
=D2*E2
```

this will give the value you of each individual chocolate level in stock

in column G generate a list of brands

in H2 use the following formula and copy down as needed

```
=SUMIF(B:B,G2,E:E)
```

[image: POC]