# Convert column number to column letter in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following VBA code to insert the column number from **Cell C1** into **Cell B1**:

```
Sub AdressColumn()
Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = Sheet1.Range("C1").Column
End Sub
```

In this case the result on my spreadsheet looks like this:

```
    A     B    C
1         3
2
3
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, instead of inserting the `3` I would prefer to insert the letter of the column. In this case the letter `C` should be inserted into **Cell B1**.

I also tried to go with the formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter) but I could not make it work since in my case I do not use a given number. Instead I refer to a Column with the `.Column` function.

What do I have to change in my formula to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the $ out of an absolute cell address.

```
Sub AdressColumn()
    Sheet1.Range("B1").Value = split(Sheet1.Range("C1").address, "$")(1)
End Sub
```

... or split the colon out of the relative full column address.

```
Sub AdressColumn()
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = Split(Sheet1.Range("C1").EntireColumn.Address(0, 0), ":")(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

user4039065 is very close, but the subscript at the end of the line should be `(2)`. Then, e.g., 677 represents column "ZA" and column 16384 represents "XFD" by the function below:

```
    Const MAX_COL_NUMBER = 16384
        ...
    Function columnNumberToColumnString(col As Integer) As String

      If col > MAX_COL_NUMBER Or col < 1 Then
        columnNumberToColumnString = "ERROR":     Exit Function
      Else

        columnNumberToColumnString = Split(Columns(col).Address, "$")(2)

      End If

' delete code block below after seeing how Split works
msg = "Split <" & Columns(col).Address & ">"
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(Columns(col).Address, "$"))
        msg = msg + Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Substring " & i & _
              " is <" & Split(Columns(col).Address, "$")(i) & ">"        
    Next
MsgBox msg       


  End Function
```

In fact, if I use `(1)` in place of my `(2)`, for column 26 I get `Z:`, not just `Z`, as explained below.

The `Split` function, when used with a valid Excel column address, returns an array  of length 3, showing in stages how the final result is arrived at.

For 256, for example, the results displayed by the `msg` code block are:

```
Address of column number 256 is <$IV:$IV>
Substring 0 is <>           (since first $ is first character, strip it and all after)
Substring 1 is <IV:>        (since second $ is after the :, strip it and all after)
Substring 2 is <IV>         (since : above is a usual delimiter, strip it)
```

`Split` "Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing ... '*all substrings*' " (if the `limit` (third) argument is omitted) of the given expression (first argument).