# Excel - How could i progress through the excel column name sequence?

Tags: excel

I need to generate the following sequence of letters:
(A, D, G, J, ..., Y, AB, AG, ...).

Basically, these letters are just the names of every 3rd column in an excel worksheet starting from the first column "A".

I know this is easy to do with numbers, you can just start off the sequence as:
(1, 4, 7, 10) and just drag to continue the pattern. But is there an easy way to do the same with letters?

Note that once the end of the standard alphabet, the sequence goes into 2 letter names as well.

Thanks!

Comment: repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter    Function to convert column number to letter.  Feed every third number to that function.

Comment: Please tell me you are not using that in an INDIRECT function.  There are much better ways than converting a string to a reference.

Answer (score 1):

=IF(A1>26,CHAR(INT((A1-1)/26)+64),"")&CHAR(MOD(A1-1,26)+65)

Function call found from the link provided by the user "donPablo".
Link is:
stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/…

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to generate the letters at all when you can access the columns using the column number directly.  Also not sure how you want this displayed.

But in case I missed something, if you have Excel O365, one method (for every third column form `A` to `KL`):

```
=LET(x,ADDRESS(1,SEQUENCE(100,,1,3),4),LEFT(x,LEN(x)-1))
```

[image]