# How do I get the last column address

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to get the last column number but I am trying to get he last column address. So if the last column is 5 then the result I am looking for is "F"

```
Sub LastColumnInOneRow()
Dim LastCol As Integer
With Sheets("Current Pipeline")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
MsgBox LastCol
```

End Sub

Comment: Why?  You can just use `Cells()` which allows the use of the column index and does not need to be converted to a string just to be converted back to an index.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed MUCH in the past.
From [Function to convert column number to letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973) :

```
Sub sub1()
  Dim LastCol&, LastColLtr$
  LastCol = 6
  LastColLtr = Split(Columns(LastCol).Address, "$")(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please consider voting to close as duplicate, instead of (re)posting the same information in yet another answer.

Comment: And we should make sure that the OP is wanting this for a legitimate reason(of which I cannot think of any) and stop perpetuating the need to convert column references to  letters in vba, which is poor coding as well as very slow.

Comment: Scott, I am not sure why you are saying this. I am not "perpetuating" anything, I am simply asking for help. Clearly I am not a professional coder and would not be familiar with good coding so all my coding is poor. This forum is to help people not to chastise them for "poor" coding

Comment: @MEC I am not chastising you.  I am chastising dcromley.  I asked the question in the comments.  If you had said it is to use the column reference in a `Range` object I would have written up an answer showing/teaching the proper way to use and handle column Index and then added a link to another question as to why using string column letters slow the code.  I knew about the dup and could easily closed it as such, but was waiting for your response, which is what dcromley should have done.

Comment: apologies Scott, I did not understand the exchange of comments, my apologies.

Comment: In any case I was able to get the answer I needed from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-do-i-get-the-last-column-address.1220767/post-5969704

Comment: @MEC take a moment and look into `Cells()` object.  If you are converting a number to a letter to use in a `Range()` object, just note that vba converts that back to an index.  All this converting is slow and can be avoided with the proper use of the `Cells()` object.  But I am glad you got your answer none the less.

Comment: @BigBen  Got it.