# Getting the column characters from Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make range in Excel VBA from the following:

1. Find the cell with a phrase (this is expected to be unique per sheet)
2. Make that entire row of used cells a Range object so I can use the Find command on it

1 is easy and done. Let's say it is cell $A$34. For 2 I want the last cell in row 34 with a value, say, cell $RS$34.

Then I can set variable *= Range($B$34:$RS$34)* and use range commands on it.

I can use the *UsedRange.Column* property to get the numeric equivalent of "RS" but is there a an inbuilt way to get the "RS"?

Edit:

Found solution in a not accepted answer here [Function to convert column number to letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)

Use *.Cells(Row, Column).Address* to return a classic Excel cell reference. Forgot to think recursive enough when applying Excel commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to convert column number to letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)

Comment: @braX Thanks, yes, but wondering if there is a built in I do not know about.

Comment: @braX One of the "not answers" is what I was after.  .Cells(Row,Column).Address will give me the "proper" cell reference.

Comment: Yes, that topic gives you lots of options - what works best depends on the full solution.

Comment: Why do you need the Letter representation? Seems simple to just use the column number in the `Cells` property to set the range.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld You are right. I did not try that until just now. Set Rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1), ws.Cells(1,10)) does the job too.