# How to add a row and button into a spreadsheet and then delete that inserted row using the button

Tags: excel

I have created a spreadsheet that allows you to pick an option from a drop down list and then shows some corresponding code. I have created a macro that inserts a new row and shifts the table down, it also adds a button on the end of the inserted row that is meant to delete the row it is on. However, it always deletes the same row. Is there a way to add a macro that deletes the row it is in?

Comment: you need to determine what row the button is on/over, something like this may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21545710/212869

Comment: Ok thanks that has helped with the row number for the button. How would you use this to select and delete the entire row?

Comment: You modify your existing macro to use the row number you find under the button instead of the constant value it likely uses. If you provide your code I may be able to help further however its likely there is a question here on SO that shows you how to remove a chosen\specific row too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA: getting row of clicked button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242605/excel-vba-getting-row-of-clicked-button)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.